# Использование разных переменных при реализации интерфейса

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Разбираюсь в интерфейсах, никак не могу решить такую задачу:
Есть интерфейс, есть 2 объекта которые его реализуют, но по окончанию их работы каждый объект выдает набор переменных присущих этому объекту.
Прошу подсказать, может быть я выбрал не верный метод реализации?

Привожу пример кода:

```
class Program
    {
        //variables
        static Dictionary<string, ISignal> signals = new Dictionary<string, ISignal>();

        //constructor
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create signals
            signals.Add("SimpleSignal", new SimpleSignal());
            signals.Add("ComplexSignal", new ComplexSignal());

            //since the signal1 is selected, we take its settings, but a signal2 can also be selected
            Dictionary<string, object> settings = signals["SimpleSignal"].ReturnSettings();

            //output
            Console.WriteLine(settings["a"]);
        }
    }

    //enum
    enum TypeEnum { FIRST, SECOND };

    //signal interface
    interface ISignal
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> ReturnSettings();
    }

    //first signal
    class SimpleSignal : ISignal
    {
        //variables  
        int a = 5;
        int b = 6;
        Dictionary<string, object> settings = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        //constructor
        internal SimpleSignal()
        {
            //create settings
            settings.Add("a", a);
            settings.Add("b", b);
        }

        //return setting function
        Dictionary<string, object> ISignal.ReturnSettings()
        {
            return settings;
        }
    }

    //second signal
    class ComplexSignal : ISignal
    {
        //variables        
        double g = 5.5;
        double s = 4.4;
        TypeEnum TypeEnum = TypeEnum.FIRST;
        Dictionary<string, object> settings = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        //constructor
        internal ComplexSignal()
        {
            //create settings
            settings.Add("g", g);
            settings.Add("s", s);
            settings.Add("TypeEnum", TypeEnum);
        }

        //return setting function
        Dictionary<string, object> ISignal.ReturnSettings()
        {
            return settings;
        }
    }
```

а вот как я хочу получать доступ к переменным, чтобы у каждой был свой класс реализующий набор "настроек" для конкретного объекта

```
class Program
    {
        //variables
        static Dictionary<string, ISignal> signals = new Dictionary<string, ISignal>();

        //constructor
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create signals
            signals.Add("SimpleSignal", new SimpleSignal());
            signals.Add("ComplexSignal", new ComplexSignal());

            //since the signal1 is selected, we take its settings, but a signal2 can also be selected
            SimpleSignalSettings simpleSignalSettings = signals["SimpleSignal"].ReturnSettings();

            //output
            Console.WriteLine(simpleSignalSettings.a);
        }
    }

    class SimpleSignalSettings
    {
        //variables
        internal int a;
        internal int b;

        //constructor
        internal SimpleSignalSettings(int a, int b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут проблема не в понимании интерфейсов, а чуть раньше

Удали интерфейс и поиграйся пока что с классом `SimpleSignal`. Метод `ReturnSettings` этого класса возвращает `Dictionary`, поэтому когда ты вызываешь этот метод из `Main` - тебе возвращается объект типа именно `Dictionary`. Класс `Dictionary` не имеет открытого поля/свойства с именем а.

Чтобы было именно так, как ты хочешь - надо чтоб возвращаемый тип у функции `ReturnSettings` был `SimpleSignalSettings`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно именно то что я написал, реализовать интерфейс и возвращать разные "настройки". Вообщем уже сам разобрался

Comment: @K.Oleg если разобрались, то можете написать ответ со своим вариантом решения и пометить его как правильный, если другие ответы не подошли.